# rxjs nested observable and combine results

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm trying to nest 2 observable and subscribing to both of their results but I cant figure out how to do it.

I want to run the first observable, Use it's result in the second observable and in the subscribe function get both first observable result and the second one..

I've made a very simple example of what I want [here](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=Rx.Observable.of%281%29%0A.map%28x%3D%3Ex%2A2%29%0A.subscribe%28res%3D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2FI%20want%20to%20get%20in%20the%20res%20object%20both%20the%20number%201%20%28From%20first%20observable%29%20and%20the%20number%202%0A%20%20%2F%2F%28Result%20of%20the%20second%20one%29%0A%20%20console.log%28res%29%3B%0A%7D%29)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating your snippet, you can simply do something like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of(1)
.map(x=>{
  var y = x * 2;
  return {x, y};
})
.subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res.x, res.y);
})
```

Or, if in the map you intended to use an Observable:

```
Rx.Observable.of(1)
.switchMap(x=> {
  var y = x * 2;
  return Rx.Observable.of({x, y});
})
.subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res.x, res.y);
})
```

And using a function:

```
function simpleAndDouble$(x) {
  var y = x * 2;
  return Rx.Observable.of({x, y}); 
}

var obs1$ = Rx.Observable.of(1)
.switchMap(x=> simpleAndDouble$(x))
.subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res.x, res.y);
})
```

**Update**, as your request in comment:

```
const subscription = Rx.Observable.of(1)
    .mergeMap(x =>
        Rx.Observable.of(x * 2),
        (x, y) => {
            console.log(x, y);
        })
    .subscribe();
```

**Update**:

```
    const one$ = Observable.of(1);
    const two$ = one$.map(x => x * 2);
    const subscription = Observable
      .merge(one$, two$)
      .map(n => [n])
      .reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
      .subscribe((a) => {
        const [x, y] = a;
        console.log('x:', x);
        console.log('y:', y);
      });
  }
```

Comment: So I have to "manually" return the first observable response inside of the second one? There is no other way?

Comment: I've updated my response so that you have the two values in one place

Comment: Can I make the subscribe function to get the x any y values or just the inside of the mergeMap ?

Comment: I've updated the response with one possible solution that actually works.

Comment: This is the closet answer to what I want.. If we consider performance issues, The merge , map and reduce operators wont effect it? It looks like multiply data set refactor for getting that..

Comment: It depends on the use case. you, sure can do a neater job by combining the operators together. For instance if the two first Observable doesn't complete the reduce will continue to .. well, reduce. And you can get rid of the map by implementing a push in the reduce.. and so on.

Comment: OK.. Thanks @pliski

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. I would choose 'combineLatest'.
CombineLatest takes multiple observables and starts to emit values as soon as all source observables emitted at least one value

```
let combinedObs = combineLatest([observable1, observable2]);
combinedObs.subscribe((val1, val2) => {
    return val1 * val2
});
```

[combine Latest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md)

Comment: I'm familiar with the  combineLatest operator.. But that's not exactly what I want..   I still need a way to use the 'observable1' response in 'observable2' and then return them both...

Comment: I don't exactly get your use-case. Can't you create a new stream from 2 existing ones to build up the values you need?