# Combine Observable subscription results in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscribe

(1) I have a request in Firebase firestore where I get several 'nomBu' strings from a collection. **OK**

(2) Then, with these recovered 'nomBu' strings, I make a second request to get metedata from another collection where the 'nomBu' is present. **OK**

(3) I would like to display data in a dashboard in HTML. **OK** **But I can only get 1 observable result in my dashboard (the last one executed)**

My code (1 and 2 and 3)

```
demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[];

fire.collection('businessUnit')
.where('evaluators', 'array-contains', this.auth.currentUserEmail).get() //(1)
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
//for each matching 'nomBu' get his metadata
this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => { //(2)
              this.demandesSaaSEvaluator = actionArray.map(item => {
            
                return { //display in HTML (3)
                  id: item.payload.doc.id,
                  ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
                } as Demande;
              
              });
            });
            });
           });
```

My code (2)

```
getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(nomBu) { //should be executed several time
    return this.firestore
      .collection('solutions', ref => 
        ref.where('businessUnitOfSolution', '==', nomBu).where('type', '==', 'SaaS')
      )
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

My code (3)

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let demande of demandesSaaSEvaluator; let i = index">
      <td>{{ demande.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.solutionName }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.nomBu }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.user }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With that code I can only display/get one observable result (the last one executed) => I would like to combine all observable subscription results to display the dashboard with all executed request results.

Workaround: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518285/how-to-combine-the-results-of-two-observable-in-angular) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078983/rxjs-nested-observable-and-combine-results)

Answer (score 1):

`demandesSaaSEvaluator` is reassign every time the observable emit something. If you want to keep the previous values, you should make `demandesSaaSEvaluator` an array and push a new value every time the callback is called :

```
this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => {               
  this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(actionArray.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.payload.doc.id,
      ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
    } as Demande;      
  }));
});
```

If you want a flat array to displat all the elements in a single list in your template, you can use the spread operator like this :

```
this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(...actionArray.map(item => {...
```

Comment: Not working even if I edit my declaration like demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[] = [];  I get Type 'Demande[]' has no properties in common with type 'Demande'

Comment: Did you use the spread operator ? If not the type of `demandesSaaSEvaluator` would be `Demand[][]`, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes that's working good thanks I have all my results but in double in my dashboard do you know how to avoid that ? Perhaps the return is misplaced or this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(...actionArray.map(item => { misplaced parethesis ?

Comment: Oh that's weird, maybe you should check the calls of the subsription callback to verify if it is called twice by values. A quick workaround would be to filter the values in demandesSaaSEvaluator containing an id that is already there

Comment: even if i just have one 'nomBu' result gaves me 3 same duplicates, this is caused by  this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(...actionArray.map(item => {

Answer (score 1):

You can zip your observable and return the return the desire result:

```
fire
  .collection("businessUnit")
  .where("evaluators", "array-contains", this.auth.currentUserEmail)
  .get() //(1)
  .then((snapshot) => {
    zip(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).pipe(
          map((actionArray) =>
            actionArray.map((item) => ({
              id: item.payload.doc.id,
              ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object),
            }))
          )
        );
      }).subsribe(result => this.demandesSaaSEvaluator = result.flat() )
    );
  });
```

Comment: for the ligne snapshot.map((doc)   I get Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData> I think is from parenthesis misplaced

Comment: Indeed, it should be `snapshot.docs.map`

Comment: line actionArray.map((item) =>  I get Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown' then line .subsribe(result => this.demandesSaaSEvaluator I get Property 'map' does not exist on type 'any[]' both are linked I guess

Comment: You should type the function `getEvaluatorSaaSRequests`, it would ease your job

Comment: i don't really understand by "You should type the function getEvaluatorSaaSRequests"

Comment: So you will be sure about the type returns by the function. It will help you to better understand what's going on